# Does buying a Team Fortress 2 item on the community market through the Mann Co. store upgrade your account to premium?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I noticed in the Team Fortress 2 Mann Co. store that some items shown are on the Steam community market, as shown in the screenshot below. If you buy one of those items through the Mann Co. store, (say, the cheapest one) does it upgrade your TF2 account to Premium?

[image: As you can see, several items are on the Steam Community Market]

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: If your account isn't upgraded to premium yet, I would simply test this by purchasing the cheapest item and posting an answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No.

While the Mann Co. Store links to the Community Market, the Community Market is a separate entity.

You must buy an item from Valve itself using the Mann Co. Store, obtain an [Upgrade To Premium Gift](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Upgrade_to_Premium_Gift) item, or buy [The Orange Box](http://store.steampowered.com/sub/469/) in order to upgrade your account to premium.

Side note: The Valve Complete Pack no longer contains TF2 and will not count for this because of it.

Now that the Giftapult item is gone, the cheapest items on the Mann Co. Store is likely the same items you unlock via achievements, such as the Kritzkrieg.  Keep in mind that you can "rent" an item first, which will reduce the amount you need to pay to buy it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to sell some cards this weekend and buy a rented item.  On one of my games I got three of the same card from drops :P

Answer (score -1):

## Yes.

From http://www.teamfortress.com/freetoplay/faq.php:

> Q. Who has a premium account?
> If you've ever spent money on TF2, you have a premium account. This includes purchasing the game before it was Free-to-Play, activating a retail version of the game, or making a purchase in the Mann Co. in-game store.

Comment: It doesn't say explicitly that it includes items from the community market purchased through the Mann Co. Store. Are you sure?

Comment: You purchased something through the store- even if it's a community item, it should still count. A community item classifies under "anything."

Comment: We're going to have to test this one out. The FAQ was made before selling items on the community market place was an option. Unless noted elsewhere, the FAQ only states that the Mann Co (in game) store as where to buy items. (and unlock premium access, not including having the original game code)

Comment: Okay, I'll mark your answer as correct once it test it out this weekend after steam guard unlocks the market. I've read that if it is from the market your account doesn't get unlocked, so I hope you are right about it. (And even if you aren't,its only 3 cents I lose)

Comment: @SnorriChinchilla I hope I'm right too-I want the rep ;)

Comment: Oh. Hmm...http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=149039697

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can.
You can just buy the cheapest weapon from Mann Co. Store to unlock Premium.
You also have the option to take the item for a 'test run' and it will be even more cheaper (25% off).
You may read more on upgrading to premium account on [Team Fortress 2: Free-to-Play FAQ](http://www.teamfortress.com/freetoplay/faq.php).

> **Q. How do I convert my free account to a premium account?**
>   Make any purchase of any amount in the in-game Mann Co. store.
>   **Q. Will I need a credit card to play?**
>   No. However, to make purchases from the in-game Mann Co. Store you will need to use one of our [accepted payment methods](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8360-WEJC-2625#acceptedforms).
>   **Q. What is the Mann Co. Store?**
>   The finest virtual item store in the world, easily accessible from within the TF2 game client.

Comment: This doesn't answer to OP's question.

OP asked about community market via the Mann Co. Store.